# Extracting the index of occurrence of a field in a struct-generating macro

Tags: rust

Is there any way to extract the "index" (order of occurrence) of a struct field in a macro like this:

```
macro_rules! example {
    (struct $name:ident {
        $($field_name:ident: $field_type:ty,)*
    }) => {
        struct $name {
            $($field_name: $field_type,)*
        }
        impl $name {
            fn print_members(&self) {
                $(println!("{} {} {}",
                    stringify!($field_name),
                    stringify!($field_type),
                    stringify!(<<<FIELD INDEX SOMEHOW>>>),
                );)*
            }
        }
    }
}
```

such that

```
example! {
    struct SomeStruct {
        a: String,
        b: String,
        c: usize,
    }
}
```

would print:

```
a String 0
b String 1
c usize 2
```

I'm pretty sure a proc macro can achieve that (not that I knew how to write one), but is it possible with declarative macros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On nightly this is easy, using [`#![feature(macro_metavar_expr)]`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/83527):

```rust
#![feature(macro_metavar_expr)]

macro_rules! example {
    (struct $name:ident {
        $($field_name:ident: $field_type:ty,)*
    }) => {
        struct $name {
            $($field_name: $field_type,)*
        }
        impl $name {
            fn print_members(&self) {
                $(println!("{} {} {}",
                    stringify!($field_name),
                    stringify!($field_type),
                    stringify!(${index()}),
                );)*
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On stable, you can count using TT munching. You can no longer use `stringify!()`, however, because this will create a sequence `0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + ...` unexpanded. Since you are just printing, you can use the number directly:

```rust
macro_rules! example {
    (struct $name:ident {
        $($field_name:ident: $field_type:ty,)*
    }) => {
        struct $name {
            $($field_name: $field_type,)*
        }
        impl $name {
            fn print_members(&self) {
                example! { @generate_println
                    [ 0 ]
                    $( $field_name : $field_type, )*
                }
            }
        }
    };
    
    { @generate_println
        [ $index:expr ]
    } => {
        // Stop condition.
    };
    { @generate_println
        [ $index:expr ]
        $first_field_name:ident : $first_field_type:ty,
        $( $rest_field_name:ident : $rest_field_type:ty, )*
    } => {
        println!("{} {} {}",
            stringify!($first_field_name),
            stringify!($first_field_type),
            $index,
        );
        example! { @generate_println
            [ $index + 1 ]
            $( $rest_field_name : $rest_field_type, )*
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Nice! There's plenty of never-before-seen syntax for me :D I couldn't quite figure out what the status is for that `#![feature(macro_metavar_expr)]` RFC, do you have an idea?

Comment: @elskrrrrt As far as I remember, it is blocked on some question. And this is for the stabilization of `$$` and `${ignore()}`, other operators has additional concerns.